# Can't draw more than one instance

Tags: java, swing, jframe, graphics2d

I'm trying to set up a menu system with buttons; however, only one button is displayed right.

Well I found the problem, I can't create multiple instances of the Button class from one class or it's sub-classes. If I do that it doesn't create the second instance right and it will then have a missing background image. Could that have to do with the fact that I made the Button class a standart class?

Here is the main portion of the Button class, all I took out where get methods which return the values of the things in this class.

```
public class Button {
private int x, y;
private int width, height;
private Image sprite;
private data.ImageControl Image = new data.ImageControl();
private String text = "";

public Button() {
    sprite = Image.getImage("game/menu/btn.png");
}

public void setImage(String file) {
    sprite = Image.getImage(file);
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
    g.drawImage(sprite, x, y, null);
    Font_LARGE font = new Font_LARGE();

    //Find text pos
    int stringX, stringY;
    int textWidth;
    textWidth = text.length() * 14;

    stringX = x + ((width / 2) - (textWidth / 2));
    stringY = y + ((height / 2) - 8);

    font.drawString(g, text, stringX, stringY);
}
```

And here is the code for where I get the image from:

```
public Image getImage(String filename) {
    Image img;
    try {
        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("sprite/" + filename));
        img = i.getImage();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("ERROR - Unable to load image at " + filename + " loading empty image.");
        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("sprite/Physix/noImage.png"));
        img = i.getImage();
    }

    return img;
}
```

Comment: Post an SSCCE exhibiting the problem. From the code above, we can't even know how and when the draw methods are called.

Comment: 1) Dont forget to call `Graphics#dispose()` on self created Graphics Objects after drawing everything thats necessary to it. 2) Also this is not an SSCCE, SSCCE is most importantly compilable from copy and paste 3) Dont use `MouseListener` rather use `MouseAdapter` 4) Dont extend `JFrame` unecessarrily

Comment: I hope this is more helpful...

Comment: No, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that focuses on a specific problem. Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea how to put the question...mainly because I have no idea why it doesn't work...

Comment: Well I narrowed down the problem so I hope that this helps...

Answer (score 0):

What are the x and y positions?

It looks to me that you draw one button on top of the other one.

Comment: The x and y positions are for each instance of the button class different. But just in case I went back and checked, but the buttons have different positions set...

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem now by just drawing the button background outside of the button class. I have still no idea why it doesn't work, but this way it works.